# SunEditor In React - Validate Text Was Inputted?

Tags: reactjs, suneditor

## Problem

I want to validate that a user has inputted actual text into the editor, ignoring html tags and whitespace.

## Details

- I'm using the ReactJS SunEditor Component
- I'm using **Typescript**

Here's an example of the content when a user doesn't type in anything:

```
   <p><br>
</p>
```

and another

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

### Attempted Solutions

I've tried putting a regex in the `onChange` event, but it's pretty clunky and probably won't take into account all the different ways non-textual content is represented; I need a better way.

```
const regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
```

### Vague Ideas

I see that the SunEditor javascript api has a utility method, `onlyZeroWidthSpace` that returns a boolean; it may work, but I don't see how I can access it. I'm using Typescript, so maybe there's an issue there?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I am the author of the SunEditor React Component. Please the core SunEditor instance can be accessed by attaching a ref to the SunEditor component (You can review this from the [documentation](https://github.com/mkhstar/suneditor-react#about-core)). Also to get plane text (non-html text), Please use the getText method on the editor object.
Example below:

```
editorRef.current.editor.getText()
```

Notice that editorRef is the ref attached to the SunEditor Component.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a funky way of doing it that seems to work. Any other suggestions are quite welcome and invited.

```
 <SunEditor
 ...
 onChange={content => {

            const contentTestContainer = document.createElement('div');
            contentTestContainer.innerHTML = content;
            const textContent = contentTestContainer.textContent;
            
            if (textContent) {
                props.getFieldHelpers('description').setValue(content);
            }
        }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

All event handler is bind the core object.
[onChange](http://suneditor.com/sample/html/out/document-user.html#onChange)

```
editor.onChange = (contents, core) => {
   // You can use the util object
   core.util.onlyZeroWidthSpace();
}
```

Comment: This looks great, but I don't think it works for React Typescript. The Suneditor library, "suneditor-react": "^2.13.1", doesn't expose the editor object, or I'm not seeing how to get it, and the Typescript api doesn't expose `core` either: export interface    SunEditorReactProps {
  onChange?: (content: string) => void;
Is there a way to access the editor through the React implementation of SunEditor?
  onBlur?: (event: FocusEvent, editorContents: string) => void;

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
onBlur = {(e) => console.log(e.target.innerText)}
```